# Checking for Consecutive 12 Weeks of 0 Sales

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table with customer_number, week, and sales.  I need to check if there were 12 consecutive weeks of no sales for each customer and create a flag of 0/1.

I can check the last 12 weeks or a certain time frame, but what's the best way to check for consecutive runs?  Here is the code I have so far:

```
select * from weekly_sales 
 where customer_nbr in (123, 234)
 and  week < '2015-11-01'
 and week > '2014-11-01'
 order by customer_nbr, week
;
```

Comment: Just to confirm you have data for every week? no holes?

Comment: Yep, sales data for every week, no holes

Comment: What you are looking for is a window function, as e.g. available for PostgreSql, take a look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html. Maybe your database has a similar function available.

Comment: `week` is a date ? and do you have some `week_id` to do `weekid +12` ?

Comment: week is a date. I can make a week_id column pretty easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/689ef/8)**

Here is a simplify version only need a `week_id` and `sales`

```
SELECT S1.weekid start_week, MAX(S2.weekid) end_week, SUM (S2.sales)
FROM Sales  S1
JOIN Sales  S2 
  ON  S2.weekid BETWEEN S1.weekid and S1.weekid + 11
WHERE S1.weekid BETWEEN 1 and 25     -- your search range
GROUP BY S1.weekid
```

Let me know if that work for you

**OUTPUT**

```
| start_week | end_week |    |
|------------|----------|----|
|          1 |       12 | 12 |
|          2 |       13 |  8 |
|          3 |       14 |  3 |
|          4 |       15 |  2 |
|          5 |       16 |  0 |   <- 
|          6 |       17 |  0 |   <- no sales for 12 week
|          7 |       18 |  0 |   <-
|          8 |       19 |  4 | 
|          9 |       20 |  9 |
|         10 |       21 | 11 |
|         11 |       22 | 15 |
|         12 |       23 | 71 |
|         13 |       24 | 78 |
|         14 |       25 | 86 | 
|         15 |       25 | 86 |    < - less than 12 week range
|         16 |       25 | 86 |    < - below this line
|         17 |       25 | 86 |   
|         18 |       25 | 86 |
|         19 |       25 | 86 |
|         20 |       25 | 82 |
|         21 |       25 | 77 |
|         22 |       25 | 75 |
|         23 |       25 | 71 |
|         24 |       25 | 15 |
|         25 |       25 |  8 |
```

Your final query should have

```
  HAVING SUM (S2.sales) = 0
     AND COUNT(*) = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Ummmmm...You could use between 'week' and 'week', and you can use too the "count(column)" in order to improve performance.
So you only have to compare if result is bigger than 0